# c# razor functions in external file

Tags: c#, html, function, razor

I have a function on my cshtml page that checks if an entered email is valid, it works as it should, however i now need to move it into an external file, with all the other functions I've created, I cant seem to find any information on this, can anyone tell me what file extension the file should have? I know it needs to go into the App_Code folder, am I supposed to do anything special to my function? and how do I call it on my web page? My lecturer literally has no notes covering this.

```
bool IsEmail(string email) {
    //declare the return variable 
    bool rst = false;

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
    // does the string follow the regex structure?
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regex.Match(email);
    //if yes
    if (match.Success){
        rst = true;
    } else {
        rst = false;   
    }

    return rst; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Improwse Just a quick suggestion - you could refactor the code at the end there to just `return match.Success;` since you're assigning a boolean variable based on a boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a new file in `App_Code`:

```
public static class GodObject {
    public static bool IsEmail(string email) {
        //declare the return variable 
        bool rst = false;

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
        // does the string follow the regex structure?
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regex.Match(email);
        //if yes
        if (match.Success){
            rst = true;
        } else {
            rst = false;   
        }

        return rst; 
    }
}
```

Then you can reference `GodObject.IsEmail(...)` from just about anywhere.

This is probably what your prof is after, however, there are far better ways to approach this validation.

Comment: after trying that out i get  "The name 'GodObject' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: What namespace did you put it in?  You have to do one of two things - fully qualify the reference as in `Namespace.ClassName.MethodName`, or you can add a `@using` statement to include the namespace in your cshtml.

Comment: Yep! I got it thanks! I also used @functions{} around it in a cshtml file, i removed that and renamed it to a .cs file and its now working perfectly! thank you :)